# another way make Asynchronous REST API with with laravel without ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, rest, asynchronous

> Im returning to laravel
> I wanna left to use ajax for asynchronous rest services.
> someone can advice me what other libraries can i use for it.

Comment: One asynchronous protocol to look into is web sockets, and Laravel's broadcasting.

Answer (score 1):

Axios is pretty good in my opinion. It is a promise based so works very well asynchronously.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Comment: Ultimately Axios uses XMLHttpRequest internally, and really is still an 'AJAX as a concept' library.

Comment: @KurtFriars, true but I deduced he would like to know about different libraries since he mentioned what other libraries he can use for it.